# Buildfire: Can't find a plugin that I created even though I uploaded it

Tags: buildfire

I created and uploaded a plugin but when I tried to add it to my app I could not find it. I have tried searching for my plugin in the "My Features" and "Marketplace" section but could not find it anywhere. The tutorial video was also outdated so it did not help me at all. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information to give you an exact answer. However, I believe you haven't issued a license key to your App.

**Context:**
When you create a developer account you are issued a developer app to test on. This app automatically receives all new plugins uploaded. Many developers end up creating multiple apps, which is fine. However, licenses will not be automatically issued to every app you have access to. You can see how that would be problematic. You would have to do so manually (Once per app).

**Purposed Solution**
Issue a new license for your app. You can use an existing license key if there are seats left. To find more information on how to do so click here:
https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-issue-a-private-license

After creating the license key, just install it in your apps marketplace.
[image: Marketplace Install Button]

If you dont see this "Install new plugin" button in your marketplace that means your app is on a lower tier. Contact customer support to review your options to upgrade.

I hope this helps.